# How to write a text parser logic which identifies keywords from a dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, parsing

How to make a simple text parser that finds keywords and categorizes them accordingly.

Example: I have two dictionaries

```
A = {'1': 'USA', '2': 'Canada', '3': 'Germany'}
B = {'t1': "The temp in USA is x", 't2': 'Germany is very cold now', 't3': 'Weather in Canada is good', 't4': 'USA is cold right now'}
```

Now I want to pick out if the keywords from `A` are present in `B` and the result should be something like this.

```
Result = {'1': ('t1', 't4'), '2' : 't3', '3': 't2'}
```

I'm a beginner and the logic to get this is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a dict comprehension:

```
A = {'1': 'USA', '2': 'Canada', '3': 'Germany'}
B = {'t1': "The temp in USA is x", 't2': 'Germany is very cold now', 't3': 'Weather in Canada is good', 't4': 'USA is cold right now'}


{k: [k_b for k_b, v_b in B.items() if v in v_b.split()] for k, v in A.items()}
# {'1': ['t1', 't4'], '2': ['t3'], '3': ['t2']}
```

This makes every value in the dict a list rather than some being collections and others strings. That's almost certainly going to be easier to work with than a mixed type dictionary.

If your dicts are going to be large, you might pick up some performance by inverting the `B` dictionary so you don't need to scan through each value every time.

Comment: Just beat me to it.. I don't think you need v_b.split() as 'in' works on strings

Comment: @JeffUK I used `split()` so it would only match whole words, i.e. so `any` doesn't match `Germany`.

Comment: Thankyou this works mostly, what do you mean by inverting the B dict for performance?

Comment: @Parzival I mean a dictionary where the keys are the words and the values are a list of labels from `B`. Something like `{'usa': ['t1', 't4'], 'very': ['t2'], ...}`. This will allow instant lookups of the words at the cost of building the dictionary once. Whether that helps or hurts performance depends on what you are building.

Comment: It doesn't work for dict values like "`temp in USA-good`" It's not considering USA as its attached to the hyphen. Any solutions for that?

Comment: @Parzival you need to decide what is and isn't considered a word boundary and split into tokens based on that. If you have complicated input, you will probably need to use a regex with  [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.split). For example to split on non-word characters: `re.split(r'\W+', v_b)` instead of `v_b.split()`. Tokenizing strings can be non-trivial once you start to get punctuation and edge cases.

Comment: Thankyou that worked perfectly, could you guide me as to how I can implement the inverted logic? this is just a personal project so no complicated edge-cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240581/discussion-between-parzival-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact formatting you have shown, you could do something like this.  A simple loop that makes a dict of tuples, and then using dict comprehension to reformat the ones that have a length of 1.

```
Result = dict()
for ka, va in A.items():
    Result[ka] = tuple(kb for kb,vb in B.items() if va in vb)

Result = {k: (v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v) for k,v in Result.items()}

print(Result)
```